# Corona SDK - app not appearing on iOS 9.3 device

Tags: ios, xcode, coronasdk, provisioning-profile, provisioning

I've updated xcode and I am using the latest build of corona.  when i build my app to my phone i'm not getting any errors..  but the app never appears on my phone.

I never noticed ideviceinstaller showing a list of commands this way though.

[image]

I've tried reissuing provisioning profiles and reinstalling Xcode. No change.

**EDIT** 
So i dragged the app file into xcode devices manager and was able to load it that way..  could it be my problem is primarily ideviceinstaller related?

Comment: Sorry, could you post a clear picture?

Comment: yeah sorry i uploaded from my phone.   not sure why it came out that way

Answer (score 0):

Last Corona Public Release with last XCODE release build for iOS 9.2 not 9.3.